# Loading Facebook Script on Mouseover (HTML5)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html

I would like to be able to load the facebook comments script on mouseover.  I am trying to get the script to load after a visitor moves the mouse over an image that says comments.  I have figured out how to do this with the facebook likes using iframes but cannot get the new comments script (HTML5) to work this way and would prefer using the facebook html5 code with a mouseover event.  I have tried various code but have not been able to get it working.  Has anyone done this and if so how did you go about it?  Here is a link to one page with how I added the facebook like script for both the video and my page.  My website load very quickly and I don't want 3 party scripts slowing it down.  This way the visitor can choose if the script is loaded and weather or not to leave a comment or like.  Thanks for the help guys!

http://www.steelheadstalkers.com/quick-clip_oregon_brown-trout_fishing.htm

Answer (score 1):

My sense would be that trying to add the initial script tag, `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`, dynamically might cause too much lag.  You'd then have to wait for the script to load before proceeding per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479753/how-to-dynamically-load-facebook-like-button) by calling [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/).

If you can handle the initial script tag and its subsequent load and parse operations up front on page load, you can still get a little performance boost by adding the FB like tags and parsing again with FB.XFBML.parse on mouseover.

Comment: I will try it out.  Another option I tried with some success is transferring the facebook code to an iframe.  It loaded similar to the facebook like script on mouseover but the script does not expand to fit new comments. If someone could figure this out I think it would be a great addition to many websites who don't want to deal with slow load times.  Thanks.